# PHP Check if static variable has been declared or initialized?

Tags: php

I want to check if a static variable has been declared/initialized previously, e.g. if a function with a static variable is being run for the first time. See the following example code:

```
function init_i (){
    // check if $i is set??
    if(isset($i)) echo '$i is static and is set ';


    static $i=0;
    $i++;
    echo "$i<br>";
}

function run_init(){
    init_i();
}

run_init(); //output 1
run_init(); //should output $i is static and is set 2
run_init(); //should output $i is static and is set 3
run_init(); //should output $i is static and is set 4
run_init(); //should output $i is static and is set 5
```

The problem is that isset($i) never seems to prove true even though it is a static variable.  How do I check `static $i` has already been set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just omit out the default value, and it will be `null`:

```
static $i;

// check if $i is set??
if(isset($i)){
  echo '$i is static and is set ';
}else{
  // first call, initialize...
  $i = 0;
}

...
```

`isset()` returns TRUE if variable is set **and** not `null`.

I don't get what's your reasoning behind this, because you can just check the value is the initial value (`0`) and you know that's the first call...

Comment: The point is to know if the function has been run before or if it is the first time. I want the function to behave differently if it is being used in a loop. I did not think about separating variable assignment during declaration.

Comment: @user Sounds like a bad idea. Functions should not behave differently in a loop or elsewhere. Research "idempotence".

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
function init_i (){
    static $i=0;

    // check if $i is set??
    if ( $i != 0 )
         echo '$i is static and is set ';
    $i++;
    echo "$i<br>";
}
```

Comment: oops you're right.  i had 2 echo 'i is static and is set' lines in there giving me false results.  i will remove that 2nd function from my answer

Answer (score 0):

check the condition after declared the static variable

```
static $i=0;
if(isset($i)){
 echo '$i is static and is set ';
}else{
$i=0;
}
```

Comment: But then the first time function is run, the if statement will prove true.  I would like it to prove true the second time and beyond.

Comment: yeah check it in else condition as well